# Node js - public subfolder

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js server which was working fine, but now can't serve a file in a public sub folder. My code is:

```js
.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))
```

I can get files in public folder but not in `public/Movimientos`.

Comment: show the complete code..

Comment: Please show your complete index.js (where you use the `.use` function) file. And also what are the endpoints you're trying to call (or whatever action you're taking to access these subdirectories).

Comment: Questions like this need to know the following: 1) What the full URL is that is being requested by the browser?  Also, show the entire HTML tag that it comes from.  2) Where the corresponding file is in your file system relative to `__dirname` (show a hierarchical diagram that indicates where `__dirname` is and where the target file is).

Answer (score 1):

The following example serves static resources from the public folder under the root folder of your application.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//setting middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public')); //Serves resources from public folder


var server = app.listen(5000);
```

In the above example, `app.use()` method mounts the middleware express.static for every request. The express.static middleware is responsible for serving the static assets of an Express.js application. The express.static() method specifies the folder from which to serve all static resources.

Now, run the above code using `node server.js` command and point your browser to `http://localhost:5000/myImage.jpg` and it will display myImage.jpg from the public folder (public folder should have myImage.jpg).

If you have different folders for different types of resources then you can set express.static middleware as shown below.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

//Serves all the request which includes /images in the url from Images folder
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/Images'));

var server = app.listen(5000);
```

In the above example, `app.use()` method mounts the `express.static` middleware for every request that starts with "/images". It will serve images from images folder for every HTTP requests that starts with "/images". For example, HTTP request `http://localhost:5000/images/myImage.png` will get myImage.png as a response. All other resources will be served from public folder.

Now, run the above code using node server.js and point your browser to `http://localhost:5000/images/myImage.jpg` and it will display myImage.jpg from the images folder, whereas `http://localhost:5000/myJSFile.js` request will be served from public folder. (images folder must include myImage.png and public folder must include myJSFile.js)

You can also create a virtual path in case you don't want to show actual folder name in the url.

```js
app.use('/resources',express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
```